# AngularJS order by array of objects with nested values

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects like this:

```
$scope.sortableItems =
[
  {
    name: 'Blue Shirt',
    fields: {Price: 20}
  },
  {
    name: 'Pink Shirt',
    fields: {Price: 80},
  },
  {
    name: 'Orange Shirt',
    fields: {Price: 10},
  }
]
```

I need to make an `ng-repeat` field that can sort the products based on price from low to high or high to low.

I tried this:

```
.product(ng-repeat="item in sortableItems | orderBy:fields.Price")
```

But it had no effect.

Additionally I have another variable `$scope.sortFunction` which can equal `Price: Low-High` or `Price: High-Low` the end result needs to detect the value of `$scope.sortFunction` and sort based on the value of the string.  Not sure how to do that with an `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that would return price and use that function inside your orderBy

js

```
  $scope.getPrice = function(item){
    return item.fields['Price'];
  }
```

html

```
<div ng-repeat="item in sortableItems | orderBy:getPrice:false">{{item.fields['Price']}}</div>
```

order by takes a second boolean value that you can use for asc / desc ordering.

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/WdooBnd6y8szzqQJ2GtW?p=preview)**